# I have a Lenovo Flex 5 16ABR8. I've just dual boot installed Ubuntu Studio 23.04 and the touchpad and touchscreen do not work (work under Windows 11)

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, touchscreen, ideapad

I found a bug that I think may be the issue (https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216804).  It looks like a kernel patch was made to the 6.2 kernel that applied to other Lenovo Flex 5 laptops, but not the 16ABR8.  It also looks like there is a more generalized fix in the 6.5 kernel, but I'm not sure when that would make it into ubuntu studio.  I guess I could apply a kernel patch manually, but I'm somewhat reluctant to do so given my lack of recent experience with kernel patching.

Apologies if I'm not providing the right info, but this is my first time posting to this forum.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:        23.04
Codename:       lunar

$ uname -a
Linux JMP 6.2.0-1008-lowlatency #8-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jun 23 17:12:12 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_6
4 GNU/Linux


Excerpt from dmidecode==========================================================
 System Information
       Manufacturer: LENOVO
       Product Name: 82XY
       Version: IdeaPad Flex 5 16ABR8
       Serial Number: PW04WK4P
       UUID: ce5f5104-a0e7-11ed-676e-d1eeaea00cee
       Wake-up Type: Power Switch
       SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_82XY_BU_idea_FM_IdeaPad Flex 5 16ABR8
       Family: IdeaPad Flex 5 16ABR8


$ journalctl | grep i2c

Jul 23 11:39:50 JMP kernel: i2c_dev: i2c /dev entries driver
Jul 23 11:39:50 JMP kernel: i2c_designware AMDI0010:03: controller timed out
Jul 23 11:39:50 JMP kernel: i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ELAN0644:00: failed to fetch HID descriptor: -110
Jul 23 11:39:50 JMP kernel: i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ELAN0644:00: Failed to fetch the HID Descriptor
Jul 23 11:39:50 JMP kernel: i2c_designware AMDI0010:00: controller timed out
Jul 23 11:39:50 JMP kernel: i2c_hid_acpi i2c-WACF2200:00: failed to fetch HID descriptor: -110
Jul 23 11:39:50 JMP kernel: i2c_hid_acpi i2c-WACF2200:00: Failed to fetch the HID Descriptor
```

Comment: Pretty sure 6.5 (still unreleased) will be in Ubuntu 23.10, and in 22.04 netx year. If you want to test newer kernels, try the [mainline PPA](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

Comment: Are the lowlatency kernel variants included here as well or would they exist somewhere else?